# Show a Text if attribute is set to "yes"

Tags: attributes, cart, product-attribute

I want to display "it working" on default.phtml if the product is assigned to attribute [Franke] with "yes".

Please help. I have tried the below code, but it doesn't work

```
getProduct()->getAttributeText('Franke') == "Yes") {
echo "It working";
} else {
echo "It not working";
}
?>
```

Comment: @JasvirSingh Thanks for responds. it not working, it crash everything

Comment: try like this:  if($getProduct->getAttributeText('phone') == __('Yes'))

Comment: this code <?php if($getProduct->getAttributeText('franke') == __('Yes')) : ?>
                   <? echo "<p style='color: #07f5471; font-weight: bold;'>" . "It working" . "</p>" ; ?>
                <?php endif;?> it doesn't work

Comment: First issue is solved or not? And for this one check that 'franke' attribute is of type yes/no.

Comment: ohk let try something different @JasvirSingh let say you have category of special and you want show it working if a product is from category special

Comment: You want to print "Working" on Category page, on each product of category "Special" right?

Comment: everything is working now @JasvirSingh thanking you for your time

Answer (score 2):

Based on tags I guess you have an issue with loading product data on checkout cart page and let me explain 2 possible way to solve

Magento loads restricted attribute list for category collection or quote (cart) collection

**1. Add your attribute to load in cart**

In your custom extension create config file `catalog_attributes.xml`

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/catalog_attributes.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="franke"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

Don't forget to flush cache, etc. After you can receive this data from product. In case you have a boolean attribute better to check like:

```
<?php if ($product->getData('franke') === '1'): ?>
YES
<?php else: ?>
NO or NOT DEFINED
<?php endif; ?>
```

**2. Load raw attribute data from product (worst in key of performance)**

```php
$franke = $product->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(), 'franke', $product->getStoreId());
// check ($franke === '1')
```

Comment: Thank you it working perfectly

Comment: Why you downvote answer which helped you? If you found the solution please don't forget to mark your question as answered. BR

Comment: sorry but i didn't downvote anything, sorry if i missed something . i'm new here so i'm still learning things.