# how to get custom product attribute value in model file in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, custom, custom-attributes

I have created a custom product attribute using data patch in my custom module and it is visible in product configuration in admin, also when I save value in it, it get save to **catalog_product_entity_int** table, now I want to get its value in custom model but its not accessible. I tried like:

$product->getEnableSubscription() //enable_subscription is attribute name
$product->getData('enable_subscription')

I added attribute in product backend only and want to fetch its value saved from admin panel.

Comment: I think this one answer might be helpful for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/356938/show-a-text-if-attribute-is-set-to-yes/356939#356939

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk  thanks for sharing.

After adding catalog_attributes.xml file I can see my custom attribute using getData() function but it is not accessible using product object.

Comment: Its nested insides many arrays/object, can't get like $product->getEnableSubscription()

Comment: Please specify a context before I can suggest anything. If you load product the data should be available. If you want to have this attribute on category page you need to set attribute as Use In Listing.

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk its working now for all custom attributes except drodowns.    

`$products = $quote->getAllItems();    
foreach($products as $product){    
$product->getData('enable_subscription'); //not working    
$product->getProduct()->getData('enable_subscription'); //working    
}  `  
But not working for attributes of type dropdown

Comment: 1. `$quote->getAllItems()` returns quote item object (not product). 2. I guess the similar case with configurable options. You didn't specify place when you try to check

Comment: I am trying to get value in custom model file for the product added in cart

Comment: And what's wrong? `foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) { $product = $item->getProduct(); $product->getData('your_attribute'); }`. You should provide more details because I've tired to guess

Comment: using this `$product = $item->getProduct(); $product->getData('your_attribute'); ` I can get all attributes except attributes of type dropdown.  

For example:

I have two attribute in product one is boolean that is enable_subscription second is interval which is dropdown with values 1,2,3 etc  
I added both in catagory_attributes.xml file but I can access only boolean by passing attribute code to getData() similar way I tried to get interval value but it is not getting fetched

Comment: If you properly specify your second attribute and properly flushed cache - it should work. You should receive it value (not label).

Comment: seems like cache issue, working fine